# 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' django login setup without password

Tags: django

I am trying to authenticate user with the system username but I am getting below error:

AttributeError at /
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.1.15
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

---

```
if getpass.getuser() != None:
        login(request, getpass.getuser())
        if user.user_type == "1":
            print("Admin")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request, '/admin_home')
        elif user.user_type == "2":
            print("staff")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request, reverse("staff_home"))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request, reverse("student_home"))
    else:
        # messages.error(request,"Invalid Login Details")
        messages.error(
            request, "You Do No Have Access To This Application")
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Comment: What is `.getuser()` doing?

Comment: it gets the username from the system. python builtin function

Comment: but that is the system user, right? Not the Django users.

Comment: Trying to pass environ("username") / .getuser()  of the system, to the login so that it can authenticate the user whether the user is there in the database table.

Comment: but that makes no sense at all. Your server itself has usernames, that is what `environ('username')` does. But those are not users of your web application. The two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: ok so I am trying to give page access to users whose system username matches with username in the database

Comment: @RRenjithRajan: but that makes no sense at all. If you run the server in production, this will use another user (to prevent accessing files), so then it is often a username like `www-data`.

Comment: you are right, I didn't think of it when it goes to production. Thanks for your time